# Windows Virtual Keyboard

Tags: java, windows, keyboard, virtual

I have a JSP page with a button inside. When i click the button, windows on-screen keyboard will pop up.
How do I do it? 
I've done research and I've found "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osk");"
but where do I implement these line? do I put it in servlet? or at my jsp page?

`<td><INPUT type="button" value="on screen keyboard" onclick="Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osk");"/>` ?

Comment: That is completely impossible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to invoke a virtual keyboard from the web page - and this is what your JSP ends up for the user. The code snippet you have is for Java SE applications that run inside the computer, not in the browser.

What you can do is to build a similar gadget on your web page with JavaScript. There are many such solutions available already, just google for "javascript virtual keyboard". http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard is one example.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. Now I understand. :)